# Find my app in Home Screen search by keyword

Tags: ios, iphone, search-suggestion, spotlight, keyword-search

I'm pretty sure I have already read this somewhere, but I just can't find it anymore. There are a couple of apps which are found by searching after some defined keywords in the iOS Home Screen search while these keywords differ from the app name.
Have a look at this example:
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotlight searches the full app name, not only the one you see in the springboard but the one showed on iTunes.
The full app name in this case is "[barcoo ‐ Produktguide mit Barcode Reader & QR Scanner](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/barcoo-produktguide-mit-barcode/id339525465?mt=8)" so you can find it simply searching the word "scan" which is contained in "scanner"